# When the user activity increases the query time increases and application hangs

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Version: 7.3.19
mysql version: 10.4.13 (Maria DB- Community Edition)
I am running an application on Linux, using PHP and Mysql. We have multiple queries which runs perfectly fine when 20-25 people are using the application. But when the users are more than 30 users the query becomes very slow. there are more than 500 users which want to use this application. If one of the query takes 0.188844 seconds to execute, but when there are many users attempting to do the same activity at the same time, the processes becomes very slow and takes about 21.017460seconds to execute sometimes even more.

below is some of examples from slow query log:

```
===============# Time: 220601  7:42:44
# User@Host: root[root] @ WIN-MN0PM3TE06L [10.15.51.252]
# Thread_id: 41274  Schema: mahabhumi_prod8  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.188844  Lock_time: 0.000154  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 51848
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 10337
SET timestamp=1654049564;
SELECT *
FROM (`kcc_requests`)
WHERE `aadhar_num` =  'XXXXX';

===============# Time: 220601 14:12:13
# User@Host: root[root] @ WIN-MUQCJ3KLLE2 [10.15.51.250]
# Thread_id: 81466  Schema: mahabhumi_prod8  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 21.017460  Lock_time: 0.000071  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 52692
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 10337
SET timestamp=1654072933;
SELECT *
FROM (`kcc_requests`)
WHERE `aadhar_num` =  'YYYYY';
=================
```

We have put the indexes in all frequently queried columns.

is there a setup issue? is any configuration to be done to allow more users to use the application?

Comment: Cache the results in memory or in a file, and optimize your queries if possible by adding the correct indexes on the columns

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE kcc_requests; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'kcc_requests';   for basic analysis of the cause of the delay when more than 25 people are trying to get answers..

Comment: @WilsonHauck since the table has large number of columns...not able to paste the output here. how can i transmit the output to you?

Comment: @WilsonHauck 
B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'kcc_requests'; 

"Name" "Engine" "Version" "Row_format" "Rows" "Avg_row_length" "Data_length" "Max_data_length" "Index_length" "Data_free" "Auto_increment" "Create_time" "Update_time" "Check_time" "Collation" "Checksum" "Create_options" "Comment" "Max_index_length" "Temporary"
"kcc_requests" "InnoDB" "10" "Dynamic" "50819" "1003" "50987008" "0" "3178496" "6291456" "62165" "2022-06-02 12:30:56" "2022-06-03 12:25:36" \N "utf8_unicode_ci" \N "" "" "0" "N"

Comment: Post output to pastebin.com for sharing and then give us the link to allow viewing you Show Create Table report.   Thanks

Comment: @Baracuda078 we have create many index, one of them is as below:
CREATE INDEX kcc_index
ON kcc_requests (aadhar_num, universal_id,created_date);

Comment: @EzyAccountingIndia   It would be MOST helpful if you could post to pastebin.com the TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE kcc_requests; for analysis of the reason your QUERY being SLOW when more than 25 people have active concurrent requests.   Share your link from pastebin.com so we can all see the current table definition.  Thanks for the show table status.  Average row length of 1,003 is very reasonable.

Comment: @WilsonHauck please find the output here : https://pastebin.com/vjfbVZE9

Comment: Thank you, Answer with suggestions posted. Let us know execution time of suggestions when you have the new index available AND more than 25 users looking for answers.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: after recreating the indexes, there is a marked difference in the performance, on monday i will update you with more info, We are yet to make changes for SELECT * FROM (kcc_requests) WHERE aadhar_num = nnnnnnn;. will do that as well and update you. Please find the output for Show  Create Table at https://pastebin.com/Jy40V1yV
this application will be rolled out to 5000 users, will these steps be enough to accommodate 5000 users? what other steps need to be kept in mind?

Comment: @EzyAccountingIndia  There is one MORE index needing to be created, CREATE INDEX kcc_requests_ndx_aadhar_univid_crdt ON kcc_requests (aadhar_num, universal_id,created_date);   that will assist with certain query performance - the query is no longer in this post, but it was a day ago.  Please view profile and consider using SKYPE TALK with me next week.  We are in GMT -6 hours.

Comment: @EzyAccountingIndia  We hope your 5,000 rollout was successful.  Looking forward to your comment on better/worse observation.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for your solution. we plan to increase the users in phasewise manner. will keep you updated with developments. 
with your solution the CPU usage has come from 98% down to 2%.

Comment: @EzyAccountingIndia  Great news, please consider posting a Review at this URL.  https://mysqlservertuning.com/collections/shop-our-services/products/slow-query-log-analysis   Scroll down and on the right side, click on 'Write a review", please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new index DOES NOT EXIST that started with aadhar_num + other columns.

Please create it again.

Please consider testing when your system has more than 25 users
the query of

SELECT *
FROM (`kcc_requests`)
WHERE `aadhar_num` =  'XXXXX';

changed to

SELECT *
FROM (`kcc_requests`)
WHERE `aadhar_num` =  nnnnnnn;

to AVOID alphanumeric to numeric wasted CPU time before accessing your table's index.

If this does not make your query faster, you may have a corrupted index.

To create current indexes, you have two choices.
ANALYZE TABLE kcc_requests;     least time consuming
or
OPTIMIZE TABLE kcc_requests;     to recreate indexes and minimize data_free space used in the table.

PS, What you recently posted is the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE - and does NOT have the new INDEX you created later.  Please recreate your index as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need

```
INDEX(aadhar_num)
```

After you add that index, you may find other queries bubbling up to the surface as "slow".  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main queries.